# Построение графиков с помощью ggplot2 в R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

[![Не получается построить вот такой график с набором данных iris. Получается либо так:

```
ggplot(data = iris, 
           aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = Species, color = Species)) +
      scale_colour_discrete(name ="Вид ириса") +
      geom_smooth() + geom_point() +
      labs(x = "Длина чашелистника, см",  y = "Ширина чашелистника, см",
           subtitle = "Связь длины и ширины чашелистника Ирисов Фишера")+
      theme_light()
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYQkw.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYQkw.png)
[![или так:

```
ggplot(data = iris, 
       aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name ="Вид ириса") +
  geom_smooth() + geom_point(aes(group = Species, color = Species))+
  labs(x = "Длина чашелистника, см",  y = "Ширина чашелистника, см",
       subtitle = "Связь длины и ширины чашелистника Ирисов Фишера")+
  theme_light()
```

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv3iq.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv3iq.png)

ХЕЛП(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, вдруг кому когда-нибудь пригодится:

```
ggplot(data = iris, 
       aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = Species, color = Species)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name ="Вид ириса") +
  geom_smooth() + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), col = "black")+
  labs(x = "Длина чашелистника, см",  y = "Ширина чашелистника, см",
       subtitle = "Связь длины и ширины чашелистника Ирисов Фишера")+
  theme_light()+
  geom_point(data = iris, aes(group = Species, color = Species))
```